# Gmail auto-refresh rate setting?

Tags: gmail

My Gmail tab used to auto-update my inbox every 1–2 minutes, but a while ago (a couple of months?) this has changed and sometimes it refreshes only after half an hour. What caused this? Is there a simple setting to change this back? If it matters, I use Chrome and I always keep Gmail open in one (of few) tab(s).

There are several similar questions online, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere. I know that I could enable desktop notifications, manually refresh or pick from many extensions that would solve my issue, but I prefer not to do any of these options, and just keep it simple, as it used to be.